# How to do server monitoring?

Tags: performance, ubuntu, monitoring, health-monitoring

Having no exprience as devops I've just been given a project where I have to do the whole thing.

So, how do I keep an eye on usage of disk, memory, database space and access time, api reply times etc?

Comment: Does that allow me to keep track of api reply times? And api content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's imperatively impossible for any admin to keep eyes on running processes at all time, this is where Server Monitory comes handy.

Try Monit, it can be easily installed with:

```
apt-get install monit -y
```

## Monitoring:

```
nano /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Use the example config to configure what you would like to monitor, this is accessible over http or https as well, plus you don't really need to access it because it will alert you if anything goes wrong in your server.  For example, you will get an email if your memory consumption is getting higher than what you specified in the config file above, or cpu is getting overloaded, or a certain website is down.

Let's dig into it a little bit.

type `monit status` to get status like the following:

```
The Monit daemon 5.3.2 uptime: 1h 32m 

System 'myhost.mydomain.tld'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [0.03] [0.14] [0.20]
  cpu                               3.5%us 5.9%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      26100 kB [10.4%]
  swap usage                        0 kB [0.0%]
  data collected                    Thu, 30 Aug 2017 18:35:00
```

#### You can monitor virtually anything, apache, nginx, mysql, disks, process etc

### Sample monit status:

```
File 'mysql_bin'
  status                            Accessible
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        755
  uid                               0
  gid                               0
  timestamp                         Fri, 05 May 2017 22:33:39
  size                              16097088 B
  checksum                          6d7b5ffd8563f8ad44dde35ae4b8bd52 (MD5)
  data collected                    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:21:02

 File 'apache_rc'
  status                            Accessible
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        755
  uid                               0
  gid                               0
  timestamp                         Fri, 05 May 2017 11:21:22
  size                              9974 B
  checksum                          55b2bc7ce5e4a0835877dbfd98c2646b (MD5)
  data collected                    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:21:02

Filesystem 'Server01'
  status                            Accessible
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        660
  uid                               0
  gid                               6
  filesystem flags                  0x1000
  block size                        4096 B
  blocks total                      5006559 [19556.9 MB]
  blocks free for non superuser     2615570 [10217.1 MB] [52.2%]
  blocks free total                 2875653 [11233.0 MB] [57.4%]
  inodes total                      1281120
  inodes free                       1085516 [84.7%]
  data collected                    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:23:02

 Filesystem 'Media'
  status                            Accessible
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  permission                        660
  uid                               0
  gid                               6
  filesystem flags                  0x1000
  block size                        4096 B
  blocks total                      4414923 [17245.8 MB]
  blocks free for non superuser     3454811 [13495.4 MB] [78.3%]
  blocks free total                 3684839 [14393.9 MB] [83.5%]
  inodes total                      1130496
  inodes free                       1130384 [100.0%]
  data collected                    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:23:02 

 System 'mywebsite.com'
  status                            Resource limit matched
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [0.01] [0.10] [0.61]
  cpu                               2.7%us 0.2%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      1150372 kB [28.5%]
  swap usage                        184356 kB [35.2%]
  data collected                    Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:21:02
```

### Setup with alert!

Don't forget that you will receive email alert for every rule that you specified to be monitor, eg when your website "**mywebsite**" is down, or when disk space is less than 20%, or disk failure, cpu is more than x% etc.

### Install monit, check it's manual with `man monit`

Answer (score 0):

You can user Window Performance Analyzer. Xperf is also helpful. 
here is the link for the same.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh162945.aspx

Comment: you can write your own tracing for same.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

file="/var/www/html/index.html"
linebreak="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
while true
do
    echo "<html>" > $file
    echo "<head>" >> $file
    echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100">" >> $file
    echo "</head>" >> $file
    echo "<body>" >> $file
    echo "<pre>" >> $file
    date >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    uptime >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    top -b -n1 -u nobody | sed -n '3p' >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    free -m >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    df -h >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    iptables -nL >> $file
    echo $linebreak >> $file
    echo "</pre>" >> $file
    echo "</body>" >> $file
    echo "</html>" >> $file
    sleep 100
done
```

I use this script to monitoring some information like temperature, disk usage, ram, firewall and so on.

I put the results in the index of an apache. So i can call the homepage of the server and see everything.

The script refreshs every 100 seconds the results. The webpage will refreshs every 100 seconds too.

With these script and apache you can monitor the server all over the world with mobile devices or pc.

```
Mo 28. Aug 14:36:03 CEST 2017
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 14:36:03 up  1:34,  4 users,  load average: 0,10, 0,09, 0,11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Cpu(s): 14,8 us,  1,6 sy,  0,7 ni, 82,2 id,  0,5 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3949        1027         756          74        2165        2542
Swap:          4093           0        4093
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  6,0M  389M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        21G  6,2G   14G  32% /
tmpfs           2,0G   43M  1,9G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Sharepoint      476G  300G  176G  64% /media/sf_Sharepoint
tmpfs           395M   92K  395M   1% /run/user/1000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```